# Bulk delete activity based on criteria

Tags: activities

I want to bulk delete an activity (activity ID 65) across all contacts within one group.

I want anyone outside this group to keep the activity.

Is this possible? The search criteria in find activities is limited.

CIVICRM 4.6.27 - Drupal 7

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try advanced search.

Search for contacts in group "x"
with completed activities of type "y"

From search settings=- set "Display results as" to activities.

You should be able to delete the activities from the search results options.

Comment: Thanks Andy, blew my mind too when someone first showed it to me :)

Comment: Great trick! Thanks Craig.